# Using two listViews in one activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made a list view containing two childs. Now i am trying to append a series of children to each of these two childs.

I am using following procedure.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.report_main_layout);


            CharSequence[] dummyChar = {"a","b"};

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UIMainAccountListView);
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterOfMainList(this, dummyChar);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the custom adapter i am using following code.

```
 if (position == 0)
        {
            viewHolder.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.UIReportTrialBalanceListView);
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterForChildList(context, debitAccounts,sumDebit);
            viewHolder.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.UIReportTrialBalanceListView);
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapterForChildList(context, creditAccounts, sumCredit);
            viewHolder.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

All i am getting is like this, I want to extend it so that all of the accounts show, List view should `wrap content` but it is not wrapping content

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Not clear about your problem, ellaborate more what you want.

Comment: look, can you see scroll mode in both list childs? I don't want it. I want each child to WRAP Content. First i want first child to show all of its list then the second child to show its whole account list

Comment: please paste your xml file containing listview

Comment: You have having 2 ListViews and many items in the List, so probably it will have the scroll.

Comment: I think that ListView doesn't support content wrapping, because it have no sense. As I understand your issue, you should use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: @LalitPoptani I have one listview and in each of its child i am appending another listview. Can you see different account names in each child? They are children of second list view. I want it to expand to full length instead of just showing these two accounts.

Comment: if you paste your xml then might solve your issues

Comment: Agarwal, the code is too big. I think i got it. @redandblack thanks for the info. It seems this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stack two listviews and force them to take up half of their parent each.

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="2">
  <ListView 
      android:id="@+id/list1" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <ListView 
      android:id="@+id/list2" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can remove the cache color by setting `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` for each listview

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20sp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/child1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/child2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/child1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This layout for first child1 listview above the second child2 listview

Thanks